# Zonal geometry output in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, geometry, zonal-statistics

Is there a way to specify the coordinate type in Zonal geometry output in ArcGIS? I am trying to perform zonal geometry on a raster and in the resulting output, the XCENTROID and YCENTROID are in metres but I want them in decimal degrees.

The raster has a NAD_1983_Albers projection.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a setting. The only two ways/workarounds I know of would be reproject the raster to GCS first, or take the resulting raster values, extract one per zone to points, calc new centroid values in GCS, then replace/update the values in the raster.

Comment: thanks Chris, you are right, I reprojected to GCS first and then things worked...